# Get file size for SXSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there a way to get the size of Excel generated by SXSSFWorkbook.

I have a requirement to check the size of the file generated and do different things based on the size, like email directly, if size is less, and upload to a location if size is more than a certain limit.

Thanks

Comment: Create `File` object for excel file and call its `length()` method to get number of bytes in file: `File file = new File("excel.xls");
   file.length();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution: you could write your `Workbook` to a file and then analyze its size.

```
Workbook wb = ...
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("sheet.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(os);
}
long len = new File("sheet.xlsx").length();
if (len > 1024_1024) {
    // upload
} else {
    // email
}
```

If you want to restrict the file size and just fail if it exceeds this restriction, you could wrap the `OutputStream` with the following wrapper:

```
public class LimitingOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final OutputStream stream;
    private final long limitInBytes;
    private final AtomicLong bytesWritten = new AtomicLong();

    public LimitingOutputStream(@NotNull OutputStream out, long limitInBytes) {
        stream = out;
        this.limitInBytes = limitInBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        increaseCounterAndValidateNotOverflown(1);
        stream.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] b) throws IOException {
        increaseCounterAndValidateNotOverflown(b.length);
        stream.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        increaseCounterAndValidateNotOverflown(len);
        stream.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        stream.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        stream.close();
    }

    private void increaseCounterAndValidateNotOverflown(int delta) throws IOException {
        long count = bytesWritten.addAndGet(delta);
        if (count > limitInBytes) {
            throw new IOException(String.format("Output stream overflown; only %d allowed, but tried to write %d bytes", limitInBytes, count));
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
try (OutputStream os = new LimitingOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("sheet.xlsx"), 1024_1024)) {
```